# Javascript - date format

Tags: javascript

May I know what kind of date format is this 20/06/2020 00:00:00.000? Is it possible if I want to get the date only? I tried this method but it doesn't work.

```
let formDate=new Date('20/06/2020 00:00:00.000');
formDate.getDate();
formDate.getMonth();
formDate.getYear();
```

Comment: @Peter that's java solutions.

Comment: Please explain *it doesn't work*. Those functions work. They return values that your code isn't using. See [JavaScript Date Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp) for what they return.

Comment: Date constructor support the [ISO standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601): `yyyy-mm-dd` `new Date('2020-06-20T00:00:00.000')` or just timestamps number with milliseconds